# Updating XML attribute in SQL Server XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

I am trying to update a node of in my XML which is stored in a SQL Server XML column, the line below works if my XML is in a XML element but now I somehow need to change it to XML attributes, apparently the line becomes invalid after the change.

Works for XMLElement:

```
UPDATE  [Customers] 
SET  voucherXML.modify('replace value of (/ArrayOfCampaignVoucher/CampaignVoucher/Qty/text())[1] with "50"') 
WHERE  voucherXML.value('(/ArrayOfCampaignVoucher/CampaignVoucher/VouCode)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') = @VoucherCode
```

I tried changing the statement like this but no luck, no errors but `QTY` values doesn't get change to the value of `@NewQuantity`:

```
UPDATE [Customers]  
       SET voucherXML='<ArrayOfCampaignVoucher xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Qty="' + CAST(@NewQuantity AS NVARCHAR(16)) + '" />'  
   WHERE voucherXML.value('(/CampaignVoucher/VouCode)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') = @VoucherCode
```

This is how my XML looks in the SQL Server XML column:

```
<ArrayOfCampaignVoucher xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CampaignVoucher VouCode="Vouc001" Qty="16" />
  <CampaignVoucher VouCode="Vouc002" Qty="18" />
  <CampaignVoucher xsi:nil="true" />
</ArrayOfCampaignVoucher>
```

Comment: removed the `asp.net`, `c#` and `vb.net` tags - has nothing to do with any of those technologies, really..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the XQuery functions - not string together your XML like this....

Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @newquantity INT = 55

UPDATE dbo.Customers
SET voucherXML.modify('replace value of (/ArrayOfCampaignVoucher/CampaignVoucher[@VouCode="Vouc002"]/@Qty)[1] with sql:variable("@NewQuantity") ')
```

This works for me - the `Qty` attribute of the node with `VouCode="Vouc002"` gets updated to the value I defined before in a SQL variable

**Update:** to insert a new `<CampaignVoucher>` entry, use XQuery something like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Customers
SET voucherXML.modify('insert <CampaignVoucher VouCode="Vouc003" Qty="42" /> 
                       as last into (/ArrayOfCampaignVoucher)[1]')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, would you kindly provide me with an example on inserting a new attribute: adding another row of VouCode and Quantity as well as deleting an attribute based on VouCode. I am trying to source for tutorials on this with little luck. Thanks!

Comment: @user415795: check out this three-part series on "15seconds" : http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050803.htm

Comment: Here's an answer that shows how to _add_ an attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46734282/8479