# How do you add attributes to an existing Root XML Node using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I've constructed some XML in TSQL.

```
declare @requestXML xml

set @requestXML = (
select @dataXML
for xml raw ('rtEvent')
```

The general output for what I now have follows the pattern resembling this:

```
<rtEvent>
  <ctx>
    .....
  </ctx>
</rtEvent>
```

What I'd like to do now is add some attributes and values to the rtEvent root 
element node but I'm not certain how to achieve it.

I've looked at the Modify method of the XML object and have observed the insert, replace value of, and delete operations but cannot seem to figure out how to use any of them to achieve the results I'm after.

Basically, I want to be able to modify the root node to reflect something like:

```
<rtEvent type="customType" email="someaddress@domain.com"
  origin="eCommerce" wishedChannel="0" externalId="5515">
   <ctx>
     ...
   </ctx>
</rtEvent>
```

Should I be using the documented XML.Modify or is there a better method? How should it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better use `FOR XML PATH`, which allows you to specify the naming and aliases as you like them:

```
SELECT 'SomeContext' AS [ctx]
FOR XML PATH('rtEvent')
```

This will return this:

```
<rtEvent>
  <ctx>SomeContext</ctx>
</rtEvent>
```

But with the right attributes you get this:

```
SELECT  'customType' AS [@type]
       ,'someaddress@domain.com' AS [@email]
       ,'eCommerce' AS [@origin]
       ,0 AS [@wishedChannel]
       ,5515 AS [@externalId]
       ,'SomeContext' AS [ctx]
FOR XML PATH('rtEvent')
```

The result

```
<rtEvent type="customType" email="someaddress@domain.com" origin="eCommerce" wishedChannel="0" externalId="5515">
  <ctx>SomeContext</ctx>
</rtEvent>
```

Answer (score 10):

Just in case you wanted to see the modify method way of doing it:

```
DECLARE @requestXML XML = '<rtEvent><ctx>...</ctx></rtEvent>'
SET @requestXML.modify(
    'insert 
    (
        attribute type {"customeType"},
        attribute email {"someaddress@domain.com"},
        attribute origin {"eCommerce"},
        attribute wishedChannel {"0"},
        attribute externalId {"5515"}
    )
    into (/rtEvent)[1]')
SELECT @requestXML
```

it returns this:

```
<rtEvent type="customeType" email="someaddress@domain.com" origin="eCommerce" wishedChannel="0" externalId="5515">
  <ctx>...</ctx>
</rtEvent>
```